# caption problem with longtable

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, lists, longtable

I wrote a code that changes the format of the output list of figures and list of tables to be Table 1 , Table 2 .......... and Figure 1 , Figure 2 ............ instead of 1,2,........

This code works fine but when I tried it with long tables it produces an error

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}% required

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][\@empty]% #1 = short caption (optionl), #2 = caption
{\refstepcounter\@captype
 \caption@caption*{\csname fnum@\@captype\endcsname{: }#2}%
 \ifx\@empty#1
   \addcontentsline{\csname ext@\@captype\endcsname}{\@captype}%
     {\csname\@captype name\endcsname\space\arabic{\@captype}: #2}%
 \else
   \addcontentsline{\csname ext@\@captype\endcsname}{\@captype}%
     {\csname\@captype name\endcsname\space\arabic{\@captype}: #1}%
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%Creating list of tables and list of figures

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\LARGE{Tables}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\LARGE{Figures}}
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage

\begin{table}
\mycaption{A sample table.}
\end{table}

\begin{small}
\begin{longtable}{| p{0.05\linewidth} | p{0.3\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.1\linewidth} | p{0.2\linewidth} |}
BLA & BLA
&  ++ & ++ &  ++ 
& BLA
\\ \hline
\mycaption{\textbf{BLABLABLA}}
\end{longtable}
\end{small}

\begin{figure}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{1.1}%
\caption{normal caption}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{2.6}%
\mycaption{my caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error is: undefined control sequence in this line

```
\mycaption{\textbf{BLABLABLA}}
```

Any help?

Comment: You didn't respect the syntax of longtable for the caption: it has to be inserted in the `\endfirsthead` section of the code, and possibly repeated in the `endhead` section.

Comment: when I use \caption instead of \mycaption there is no error. so this is not the problem

Comment: the definition of `\caption` in longtable is completely different to the definition of `\caption` in `figure` you can not expect the same `\mycaption` to work in both places.  longtable captions do not use `\refstepcounter` and need to generate a spanning table entry. In general to customise the list of tables entries you should be able to set `\l@table` you should not need to redefine the top level caption command.

Comment: Don't change the `\caption` code for changes to the LoF or LoT, use the `tocloft` package instead.